# Twitter Bootstrap (and similar CSS frameworks) folder location

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

What would be the pros and cons of putting the `bootstrap` folder from the official Bootstrap distribution in the `css` or `styles` folder of an app, vs. putting it in a more generic `assets` directory or as a top-level folder directly beneath `public` or `www`?

Since Bootstrap is primarily concerned with CSS, my initial inclination was to put it in my `css` folder, but it has images and Javascript as well so I'm not sure if that's the best place for it. As to the Javascript included with Bootstrap, it's very visually oriented so perhaps keeping everything in the `css` folder still makes sense.

It's probably obvious that my question isn't specific to Bootstrap, but is relevant to any CSS-oriented framework with this type of structure, for example: http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/.

My goal is to keep things easy to work with both for me and for other programmers new to my app. Are there other factors beyond deciding on a logical location that I should consider? For example how the folder structure might impact LiveReload for LESS or SASS files (especially if I wanted to extend Bootstrap classes using Less)?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider Yeoman that manages all that. 
http://yeoman.io/

Comment: Or a more generic helper like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) (which Yeoman employs) but either way, I'm a big proponent of putting components outside of the web directory (preferably managed by something so they are easy to install and update and don't have to be checked into the repo) and having a build system that gathers/concats/minifies into a release folder ready for deployment.

Comment: @steveax So you put all your source files for public assets like CSS and JS in a single folder that lives above the web root? So if you had an MVC app then you would have the folders `controllers`, `models`, `views`, `lib`, etc. and also an `assets` folder where all the CSS/JS/images would go?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I think I should definitely use something like that (actually I've already been looking into LiveReload which I think should be able to handle minification, compilation, etc.)...but I'm still unclear on what the directory structure would look like (both above and below the web root).

Comment: The key to using something like Yeoman is you let it decide what's best in other words it's opinionated.